# Is there any saying in Islam about getting sad, depressed, or anxious?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

I was an introvert kid. My upbringing was quite regular kinda desi. Just like we have in Pakistan. Also my family is Islamic. Sometime I question about Islam and they would just shut my mouth. I'm 22, and while living in a third world country I don't feel good here. I sometimes get depressed, anxious, having an anxiety is common. I don't take any medicines and I don't have any family support in this regard. No one is there to support me. No one listens me and this thing affects my relationship with my siblings and parents. I sometimes misbehave them unintentionally. I used to feel ashamed while doing this with them, I always said sorry. But now, it's like they would answer harshly and negatively and it's like I don't regret that much after misbehaving with them. My family says there's no point of being depressed or sad in Islam. Is that true? Those who feel depressed and anxious aren't Allah's favourite people because they've said this. I'm educated I know things but I want an islamic perspective on this. what Islam says about depression? And how can we get rid of it? My mental health is just destroyed and my physio health is determined day by day. I'm feeling sick almost on every day. Whenever I'm around my family, it's exhausting and want to escape from them.

Answer (score -1):

yes, its true there is no point of being sad or depressed but sometimes we feel that way but remember we are only humans even the prophet (PBUH) there was a time he felt that way and Allah comfort him with Surat Duha. مَا وَدَّعَكَ رَبُّكَ وَمَا قَلَىٰ﴾ Your Lord has not forsaken you, nor does He hate you.
‎﴿وَلَلْآخِرَةُ خَيْرٌ لَّكَ مِنَ الْأُولَىٰ﴾ And indeed, the Hereafter is better for you than the present (life of this world).
‎﴿وَلَسَوْفَ يُعْطِيكَ رَبُّكَ فَتَرْضَىٰ﴾ And verily, your Lord will give you so that you shall be well-pleased.
here is ayat that will help you, just be patient Allah is enough for us. لَا إِلَٰهَ إِلَّا أَنْتَ سُبْحَانَكَ إِنِّي كُنْتُ مِنَ الظَّالِمِينَ, and ﴿رَبِّ إِنِّي لِمَا أَنْزَلْتَ إِلَيَّ مِنْ خَيْرٍ فَقِيرٌ, when ever you are not doing anything you can just be reciting this ayat inshallah allah will help you. Be constantly reading surat (NAS AND FALQ) the last surahs in quran. may allah ease it for us.